# AWS Beanstalk and Apache VirtualHost SSL custom DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I already configured my `.ebextensions` directory to install SLL files and configure `ssl.conf` apache file. Everything is working perfect, instead the `DocumentRoot` of my `ssl.conf` that is not overwriting my Elastic Beanstalk default `DocumentRoot`.

Problem: When I access https://dashboard.mydomain.com its also pointing to `/home` instead `/dashboard` folder.

---

Elastic BeanStalk Default DocumentRoot:

[image]

---

Directory Files:

```
home/ -> Accessed by http://www.mydomain.com/
  ...
dashboard/ -> Accessed by https://dashboard.mydomain.com (DocumentRoot isn't working, its also pointing to /home)
  ...
framework/ (Secure)
```

---

ssl.conf:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName dashboard.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dashboard -- NOT WORKING
     <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/httpd/ssl/gd_bundle.crt"
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/ssl/cert.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/ssl/key.key"

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
    TransferLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 2014 feb 08**

I did some tests and I found out that the ProxyPass directive does not simply redirect every request from port 443 to localhost:80 (as one could easily thought), but basically  repeats the request to Apache from scratch, through the port 80 (at least, that's what I understood).

So, if you want to set any environment variable, you need to do it in the matching VirtualHost, adding to your .conf something like this:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dashboard
</VirtualHost>
```

This will be executed with every request (80 or 443).

**END UPDATE**

I have no idea why, but here two suggestions: the .conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d are processed in alphabetical order.
This doesn't explain why your configuration don't take over, because the environmental variables are set in aws_env.conf
BUT... take a look to aws_env.conf: you'll find some hints (it looks like the name of documentRoot is somewhat changed: for example, in my version is PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT).
Good luck, let us know if you find out.